# how janusGraph server instance come?

Tags: janusgraph

I've had a strange problem lately.When i use mgmt.getOpenInstance() in my gremlin shell, I find three instance:

```
    gremlin> mgmt.getOpenInstances()
    ==>0a05778817387-ncn2d-wiseoap-hispace-janusgraph-5-119-1369(current)
    ==>0a05604582467-ncn2d-wiseoap-hispace-janusgraph-5-119-699
    ==>0a05778853802-ncn2d-wiseoap-hispace-janusgraph-5-119-136d
```

How are these three instances generated?

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to janusgraph with gremlin-console or java code, it will creates a instance. You can close it with `mgmt.forceCloseInstance("your_instance_name")` cmd.